# Notification when some input (stdin, file, named pipe) is available?

Tags: signal

is there some mechanism to be notified asynchronously when input from a 'file' is available?

I have a program that cyclically does its work. So far so good. But there also is a serial line and whenever a message appears there the program shall react immediately, do something special and then return to its eternal loop. A bit like a hardware interrupt, but fired by the info 'some input is available

Comment: Please clarify the situation you are dealing with and the result you are looking for and include examples if possible. Your question is not quiet clear enough. Thank you

Comment: @Raffa I have a program that cyclically does its work. So far so good. But there also is a serial line and whenever a message appears there the program shall react immediately, do something special and then return to its eternal loop. A bit like a hardware interrupt, but fired by the info 'some input is available'. Best regards - M'

Comment: If yor program is managed by a shell script, you can add something in the script like `notify-send "some input is available"` right after the part where you say *"the program shall react immediately, do something special "* . It is however still unclear to me whether this is what you need. It would be helpful if you can [edit]  and add  the code that you use in your script and indicate where and how you want the notification.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if that's possible in bash, the answer is no; see also here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37049612/equivalent-of-select-system-call-in-bash

However, there is the select() system call (see "man 2 select") which you can use in scripting languages like Perl, Ruby, Python, and of course in compiled languages like C or C++, but not in bash.

What select() does is it waits until data from any of several file descriptors is available.

Comment: The reference to 'select' is helpful (I am quite new to Linux) - many thanks for that.